# How can I fix this error?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, kinect

Do you know what assembly i should add in order to fix this error?

`Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.ControlsBasics.ImagesGrid` does not contain a definition for `KinectTileButtonClick` and no extension method `KinectTileButtonClick` accepting a first argument of type `Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.ControlsBasics.ImagesGrid` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

```
    <WrapPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="wrapPanel" Orientation="Vertical" k:KinectTileButton.Click="KinectTileButtonClick">
            <!-- items for design layout.  They will be replaced at runtime. -->
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="1" Click="KinectTileButton_Click" />
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="2"/>
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="3"/>
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="4"/>
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="5" Click="KinectTileButton_Click_1" />
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="6"/>
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="7"/>
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="8"/>
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="9"/>
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="10"/>
            <Image Height="150" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" Width="200" />
        </WrapPanel>
```

Comment: Show us some code please

Comment: "are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference" ?

Comment: `Namespace: Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.Controls
Assembly: Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.Controls (in microsoft.kinect.toolkit.controls.dll)`

Comment: xmlns:local="Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.Controls"   is this right?

Comment: @user3522950 During the last two days you've asked a couple of very basic questions here. I guess it would make sense if you get one or two books about C# and WPF before you start coding your program. Seriously!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create `KinectTileButton_Click` and `KinectTileButton_Click_1` in your code behind. These are the methods you have to define to handle the click events on your buttons.

You can create them quite simply by right clicking on the name of the missing method in the xaml view and selecting the "Navigate to Handler" option. IF the method doesn't exist it will be created for you.

Once you've got the empty method you can add your click handling code.